# How to configure communication between standard env app-engine & cloudsql instance with internal ip

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, google-vpc

I configure a serverless vpc,& launch the app with following app.yaml. But unable to communicate the private sql instance.

````
runtime: python37
service: xxxx
entrypoint: gunicorn main:app --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker

vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/xxxx/locations/us-central1/connectors/serverless-vpc-name"

inbound_services:
- warmup

env_variables:
  PROJ_NAME: xxxxx
  DB_TYPE: mysql_socket
  SQL_USERNAME: root
  SQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
  SQL_DATABASE_NAME: xxxxx
  SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: xxxx:us-central1:cloudsql-instance```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip):

> If you are connecting from App Engine, you must use flexible
>   environment. You cannot use private IP to connect from standard
>   environment.

Here you can find more documentation [Connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine)

However you can use Serverless VPC Access to connect from your App Engine app directly to Cloud SQL instances, and any other resources with an internal IP address.

[Connecting to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc)

Comment: is it any option to deploy app in standard environment ?

Comment: there is no option with private IP from standard

Comment: if we deploy the app in "env: flex" with 'vpc_access_connector:' from app.yaml file, it should be connected. right ?

Comment: you can find here a related question [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/985982/how-to-connect-app-in-google-app-engine-to-mysql-in-cloud-sql-using-internal-ip)

Comment: yes , you can connect using vpc_access_connector [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access)

Comment: any new feature deployed Google recently against standard environment app-engine and sql-instance communication via private ip ?